# Using "spec" abbreviation

Tags: abbreviations

I'm using "spec" as abbreviation for "specification" in the name of my program.
The name of the program is "MeteorSpec".

My concern is that this abbreviation can be understood as "speculation". Are my fears true?

Comment: The context in which you use this abbreviation will determine its meaning. Most of the time, it will be interpreted as *specification*.

Comment: Shortening "specification" or "specifications" to spec/specs is quite common and expected, however "speculation" cannot be generally shortened in this way. For example `let me see the specifications` -> `let me see the spec` = OK. However, `There was much speculation as to the purpose of the new gadget.` -> *`There was much spec as to the purpose of the new gadget.` ("spec" no longer fits in the second sentence)

Comment: I would say that 90%+ of US English speakers would understand "spec" to be "specification".  And most of those who understood differently would take it to mean "speculative".

Comment: (And, it occurs to me, that at least 1% of the males will interpret it to have some sort of sexual connotation.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest doing some audience analysis to answer your question. In the military, spec is a standard abbreviation for specification.  I believe that the technical community will most likely see this abbreviation as meaning specification.  However, if you have a non technical audience, it could be argued that spec also stands for speculation (see http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spec).